# nuxt js router is not passing data prop from one component to another

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

so i have this code that am passing prop which is house id from parent component to another component. here is my code
where would i be wrong?
  i have tried some links like this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html 
and this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/297 but its not bringing any success

```
//parent component

<v-flex sm5 mt-3 mr-2 v-for="houses in getadminhousesummary" :key="houses.id" >
                  //link    <nuxt-link :to="'Building/'+houses.id" :house = "houses" >  
                    <v-card >
                    <v-card-title class="primary shead justify-center"><h3><v-icon class="shead">home</v-icon>{{houses.name}}</h3></v-card-title>

                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-layout row wrap>
                        <v-flex sm12>
                            <v-icon>location_on</v-icon>{{houses.location}}
                        </v-flex>
                         <v-flex sm12>
                          <v-btn flat>{{houses.units }}Units</v-btn>
                           <v-btn flat>{{houses.booked }}Booked</v-btn>
                            <v-btn flat>{{houses.units -houses.booked  }}Empty</v-btn>
                        </v-flex>
                        </v-layout>
                    </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                     </nuxt-link>

                    <v-divider></v-divider>
                 </v-flex>

//component where i want to receive the data
<template>
    <v-container>

  <p> hello {{house}} </p>


    </v-container>
</template>


<script>

export default {
 props: ['house'],


    data(){
        return{

        }
    },`enter code here`


    layout:'building',

}
</script>
```